# Why open site inside fancybox div? using wordpress easy fancybox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I'm using Easy Fancybox on Wordpress Web Site

link:

http://lidervision.com/portal/eventos/evento-2/

for view this you must be clic on Sell Points (puntos de venta) or Program (programa) or Workship (adoracion)

and clic again in this button

Answer (score 0):

Easy fancybox uses fancybox v1.3.4 and that version has a [bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/fancybox/-re22BoXOzM) using `inline` content.

You would need to patch your fancybox script with this workaround :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   'onCleanup': function() {
      var myContent = this.href;
      $(myContent).unwrap();
   } 
});
```

... or visit the [support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/easy-fancybox) and tell the plugin developer what I said in this post ;) ... not sure if he already has a new release with the patch.